# Error (893) can't open camera by index, python and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, video4linux

The code:

```
import cv2
   
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

cntr =0
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    
    cntr= cntr+1;
    if ((cntr%30)==0):
            
        cv2.putText(frame,'cool' ,(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.imshow('Text Detection Tutorial',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xff == ord('q'):
             break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error in the jupyter-notebook window:

> 17     raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")
>
> OSError: Cannot open webcam

I have two devices, a built-in webcam `/dev/video0` and an USB webcam `/dev/video1.`

They both appear listed with `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`

Both cameras work fine with `guvcview`.

I use jupyter-notebook to run the code above.

When I use `cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)` it works fine. But when I use cap= cv2.VideoCapture(1) for the USB camera I get the next error in the terminal:

> [ WARN:0] global
> /tmp/pip-req-build-ms668fyv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp
> (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index

I tried to give all permissions to /dev/video1, `sudo chmod 777 /dev/video1.`

I'm using linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

Linux creates 2 files in the `/dev/video` for each webcam. The lower numbered one (`/dev/video0` in your case ) is for capturing stream and the following one (`/dev/video1` in your case) includes some data about camera.

So when you tried with the index number 0, it works fine and opens the camera with `VideoCapture(0)`. But what about the 2nd camera ? There may be some different reasons why it is missing:

- Current driver systems doesn't support that ( not a video4linux device or old kernel version )
- It is not usb-plugged camera.

As a result, its not bacause of `VideoCapture` can not read; its just because of you are trying to open it with wrong index which is data file of camera.

**Note:** *I suggest you to try `VideoCapture(-1)` also, this also works in some cases interestingly. Sometimes for substreams of webcams or luckiliy opening a camera's substream which has its own driver.*